# Проблема при рандоме

Tags: python

вот кусок кода

```
#Random [test]
elif command == "Random" or command == "random" or command == "Random " or command == "random ":
    request = print("Введите строку: (Минимильно 2 строки.)")
    request_inp = input(#Тут должна быть строка которую введет пользователь)
    data_reg = []
    data_reg.append(request_inp)
    gen = random.choice(data_reg)
    print(gen)
```

допустим пользователь ввел 1 и 2 и должно вывестись 1 или 2
но выведеться это

```
1 2
```

что я должен дописать помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что у вас в `data_reg` находиться одна строка и всегда будет выводится она. Вам надо разделить строку через пробел. Это легче всего сделать с помощью метода `split`

```
data_reg = request_inp.split()
```